# Is there a way to change the line type of the arrowhead in a geom_segment() with a dashed line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following issue in ggplot2. I am making a plot which needs to contain different types of arrows. I would like to use different line-types for each arrow to make the graph readable in black and white. Unfortunately, ggplot2 draws the arrowheads in the same style as the line. This leads to arrowheads that can be barely recognized as such. Is there a way to change the arrowhead to a solid line?

Toy example:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0,6)), aes(x = x)) +
 geom_segment(x = 0,
              xend = 1,
              y = 0,
              yend = 0.5,
              linetype = "dotted",
              arrow = arrow(arrow(length = unit(2,"mm"),
                            ends = "both"))
            )
```

Here a screenshot of a plot where this leads to invisible arrows:
[image: Plot showing different arrows]

Comment: How about using closed arrow heads instead of open?  Like `arrow(length = unit(2,"mm"), ends = "both", type = "closed")`

Comment: This was the right answer! Thanks.